# Where can I get .world files for stage?

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any repository where I can get them? I would like to simulate in different maps.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11592/where-can-i-get-.world-files-for-stage?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-19**:
@jlo : tinker with the codes in willow-erratic.world and willow-four-erratic.world and try changing the pgm file with other sketches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find 4 world files that I used for my simulations, here :

http://mobotica.googlecode.com/files/stage-controllers.tar.gz

http://mobotica.googlecode.com/files/volksbot.tar.gz

http://mobotica.googlecode.com/files/simple-standalone.tar.gz

Plus, there is a Stage based turtlebot simulator,

https://github.com/Arkapravo/turtlebot_stage_simulator

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2011-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple in the stage/world directory... actual path in ros electric should be:
<ros_dir>/electric/stacks/stage/world/

---

Originally posted by [Yianni](https://answers.ros.org/users/215/yianni/) with karma: 123 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-19**:
I could only find world-erratic and world-erratic-four. Are there supposed to be more?